# Understanding memory leaks and MAT on Android

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-bitmap

I'm trying to detect my memory leaks.

After watching the [video from Google](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk) and reading on StackOverflow, I'm starting to give it up because I don't find the issue.

My first Activity loads 4 images from resources (ImageView, for each one the width in pixels are not bigger than 400px), and I can find this on MAT (MainActivity):

[image]

then if I start the HomeActivity, this has more imageviews but all of them are short and small. So I load it and I get this:

[image]

but if I use *regex* with HomeActivity or MainActivity:

[image]

[image]

And this, are supposed to be my LEAKS:

[image]
[image]

**I tried to not to set some images, delete an horizontalScrollView, deleting some items which could be a problem.**

And I'm totally lost. Would you know what I'm doing bad?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My first Activity loads 4 images from resources (ImageView, for each one the width in pixels are not bigger than 400px)

First, an `ImageView` is not a resource. It is a widget.

Second, the size of the `ImageView` is irrelevant by default when it comes to loading resources.

> and I can find this on MAT

You are consuming ~26MB worth of heap for `byte[]`. If you expand that node in the tree you should see specific instances of this. If you find one of interest, right-click on it and examine its GC roots to try to identify what it is.

> So I load it and I get this

This shows two specific `byte[]` at ~12MB and ~11MB each. Right-click on them and explore their paths to GC roots to try to identify what it is.

> Would you know what I'm doing bad?

Not specifically. After all, we do not have any Java code, any resource XML, or anything much to go on.

If I had to guess, you added some large image files as drawable resources and are relying upon `ImageView` to scale them down to smaller sizes. That's fine, but `ImageView` does not reduce the heap used by the images themselves. That will be determined by the resolution of the image (width * height) and the bit depth of the image (usually 4 bytes per pixel for `ARGB_8888`). Resources are never released once loaded, compounding your problem. You can:

- Scale the image yourself at compile time to something closer to what you will actually need at runtime, and/or
- Use `BitmapFactory` and `decodeResource()`, with an appropriate `BitmapFactory.Options` instance and `inSampleSize` value, to load the image in more manually, downsampling it at runtime to consume less heap space, and loading it as a regular `Bitmap` (AFAIK, `decodeResource()` does not load the resource as an actual resource, allowing it to be better managed at runtime)

Comment: I know resources are not released, but I have an instance of Bitmap which I didn't initialize on my code (See HomeActivity or MainActivity)... and I'm just loading 40x40, 70x70 images...

Comment: @RafaFirenze: Then trace the paths to the GC roots to figure out what it is and who is holding a reference to it.

Comment: Ok, I'll try, but they seem to be infinite :P